# Is Cauchy-continuity a property of a function or its domain?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is Cauchy-continuity a property of a function or its domain?

To illustrate my question, let $f: A \subseteq \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be continuous.  Then for any sequence $(x_n) \in A$, if $(x_n) \to x \in A$, then $(f(x_n)) \to f(x)$.

Suppose there is a sequence $(x_n) \to x \notin A$.  Then it is not necessarily true that $(f(x_n)) \to f(x)$.  An example is $f(x) = 1/x$ on $(0,1)$.

If $A$ is closed, then by definition, if $(x_n) \in A$ converges, it converges to a point in $A$.  Thus, if $A$ is closed, any continuous function on $A$ is Cauchy-continuous.  Conversely, if $A$ is not closed, there exists a sequence $(x_n) \to x \notin A$, for which $f(x)$ is undefined, and therefore $f$ is not Cauchy-continuous.

If the above is correct, than Cauchy-continuous isn't a property of $f$ but rather $A$, and is synonymous with the proposition "$A$ is closed."  Why then do we discuss Cauchy-continuity as a distinct property of *functions*?

---

## Update

In light of the comments: My definition of Cauchy-continuous is:

> A function is Cauchy-continuous if it sends Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences.  That is, if $(x_n) \in A$ converges, then $(f(x_n))$ converges.

$x \mapsto 1/x$ is not Cauchy-continuous, since $(1/n) \to 0$ yet $(f(1/n))$ does not converge.  As Alex Kruckman and Anne Bauval comment, $x \mapsto x$ sends these sequences to 0, and is thus Cauchy-convergent, even if we restrict $f$'s domain to $(0,1)$.

Would it be correct to state the following:

- If a function is continuous on a closed domain, it is Cauchy-continuous in that domain
- If a function is continuous on a non-closed domain, it may still be Cauchy-continuous on that domain, as long as $(x_n) \in A \to x \implies (f(x_n))$ converges.  This condition is met even if $f(x)$ is undefined: $f$ can still be continuous on its domain, and $x$ outside of its domain.  And $f$ can be Cauchy-continuous on its entire domain because, for $x$ outside the domain, we only need that $(x_n) \to x \implies (f(x_n))$ converges, not that $(f(x_n)) \to f(x)$ (which, as Anne Bauval comments, is a nonsensical statement anyway.)

Comment: "If $A$ is not closed, ... $f$ is not Cauchy-continuous." I think this is false. For example, the identity function on $(0,1)$ is certainly Cauchy-continuous. But the  issue may be that we disagree on definitions. What is your definition of Cauchy-continuous?

Comment: The existence of a sequence $(x_n) \to x \notin A$ (for which $f(x)$ is ipso facto undefined) does *not* prevent $f$ from being Cauchy-continuous (e.g. $f=$ a constant function on $A=(0,1),$ and $x_n=\frac1n$).

Comment: If there is a sequence $(x_n) \to x \notin A$, not only is it "not necessarily true that $(f(x_n)) \to f(x)$" but it makes no sense, since $f(x)$ is undefined.

Comment: @AlexKruckman AnneBauval Appreciated! I updated with my definition and a clarification.  Please let me know if it's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be conflating "Cauchy sequence" with "convergent sequence" throughout your question. These conditions are equivalent for sequences in $\mathbb{R}$ (or any complete metric space), but not in a general metric space. And since arbitrary subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ need not be complete, this can lead to confusion.

As an instance of this, you write

> A function is Cauchy-continuous if it sends Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences.  That is, if $(x_n) \in A$ converges, then $(f(x_n))$ converges.

The definition of Cauchy-continuous is: $f$ is Cauchy-continuous if and only if for every Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ in the domain of $f$, the sequence $(f(x_n))$ is also Cauchy. In your "that is..." clause, you replaced "Cauchy" with "converges". This is equivalent if by  "converges" you mean "converges in $\mathbb{R}$", but not in general.

You are correct that if a function on a closed set $C\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then it is Cauchy-continuous. But I think it would be better to write that if a function on a *complete* domain is continuous, then it is Cauchy-continuous (and it happens that a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ - or any complete metric space - is complete if and only if it is closed). The point is that if the domain is complete, then every Cauchy sequence in the domain converges in the domain.

You are correct (in the update) that if the domain of a function is not closed, the function may still be Cauchy-continuous. A trivial example is the identity function restricted to *any* domain.

It's a total red herring to think about a point outside the domain of the function that your sequence converges to. You only need to check that $f$ sends every Cauchy sequences to a Cauchy sequence.

Last comment: Even if it *was* true that a continuous function with domain  $A$ is Cauchy-continuous if and only if $A$  is  closed, Cauchy-continuity would still be a property of the function, not the domain, just  because continuity itself is a property of the function, not the domain. There are plenty of non-continuous  (and hence non-Cauchy-continuous) functions defined on closed domains.

Comment: This clarifies a lot, thank you.  One question: "It's a total red herring to think about a point outside the domain of the function that your sequence converges to".  Consider $f: (0,1) \to \mathbb R, f(x) = 1/\sin x$.  Then $x_n  = 1/n$ is a Cauchy sequence (converging to 0, outside of $f$'s domain), but $f$ does not send $x_n$ to a Cauchy sequence.  Isn't it appropriate and necessary to consider the behavior of $f$ on such sequences which converge to _outside_ of $f$'s domain? And, in fact, aren't these the _only_ sequences which prevent $f$ from being Cauchy-continuous?

Comment: @SRobertJames Yes, that's correct. My point is that the point $0$ is not actually relevant to the discussion. $(\frac{1}{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}_+}$ is a Cauchy sequence, and $(\frac{1}{\sin(\frac{1}{n})})_{n\in \mathbb{N}_+}$ is not a Cauchy sequence, so $f$ is not Cauchy-continuous. We can see this without knowing that the sequence $(\frac{1}{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}_+}$ happens to converge to $0$ (outside the domain of $f$).